# How to override specific properties loaded from spring PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer?

Tags: java, spring, configuration

I need to change values of selected configuration properties at runtime which are loaded using spring's PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. Tried following two solutions but dint solve much,

SOLUTION 1: Used PropertyOverrideConfigurer in my configuration file. Referred [here](http://java-questions.com/spring_property_file.html)

But this solution only pushes values from overriden properties file to mentioned bean's property. But concern is, I got many beans referring to this property. All I need to override the default values at runtime at one place. This encouraged me to go for second solution below.

SOLUTION 2: Use of maven surefire plugin as mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752435/overriding-system-property-in-spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-for-integrati)

But i am not upto using any surefire for this sole purpose. Is there any spring configuration which helps me to override default property values in test profile.

Thanks. Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: What about having an override properties file?

Comment: As I understand from this, is that I have to use a override properties file ? If yes, that's similar to what mentioned in n SOLUTION 1 mentioned. OR rather is there any specific mechanism in SPRING to override default values from override properties file.

Comment: What I am suggesting, is to use the a standard practice, where Spring can read properties from multiple properties file where the properties read from later files override properties read from former ones. Such a setup is really easy to achieve in Spring. Let me know if that's what you want

Answer (score -2):

```
You can use the below code to override properties, it will print out all the properties later on you can override whatever property you want:


import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringPropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;
    private static String keyToFind = "myProperty";
    // Default as in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
    private int springSystemPropertiesMode = SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK;

    @Override
    public void setSystemPropertiesMode(int systemPropertiesMode) {
        super.setSystemPropertiesMode(systemPropertiesMode);
        springSystemPropertiesMode = systemPropertiesMode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props) throws BeansException {

        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);

        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = key.toString();         
            if(keyStr.equals(keyToFind))    {
            String valueStr = resolvePlaceholder(keyStr, props, springSystemPropertiesMode);
            System.out.println(valueStr);      
            }         
        }
    }

    public String getProperty(String name) {
        return propertiesMap.get(name).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xm`enter code here`l");

        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
    }

}
```

Comment: please explain your answer and what you have change?

Comment: Gurum wanted to override the properties loaded from PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer. In my code we can print/edit/override properties loaded in processProperties(). That's it.

Comment: The OP knows this solution and he asked for something else?